# HQL syntax error : 'NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.QuerySyntaxException'

Tags: sql, oracle, nhibernate, hql

As a beginner in HQL , I have a SQL query that I'm trying to transform into hql.

```
select * from (

   select *
   from CORRELATION_VUE
   where film = v_oldidfilm and FILM2 not in (
                           select c.idfilm
                           from cotes c
                           where idclient = v_idclient)
   order by CORRELATION desc
 
 )
 where rownum <= 3;
```

So in HQL I'm trying this :

```
ISession s = NHibernateHelper.GetCurrentSession();
ITransaction tx = s.BeginTransaction();
IQuery query = s.CreateQuery(
    @"select u from (
            select u from vueCorreliser u
                where u.film = :idfilm
                    and u.FILM2 not in (
                        select c.idfilm from cote c
                            where c.idclient = :idclient)
                order by u.CORRELATION desc)
        where rownum <= 3; ")
    .SetInt32("idfilm", idfilm)
    .SetInt32("idclient", idclient); 

IList<Film> result = query.List<Film>();
tx.Commit();
return result;
```

But I'm receiving a syntax error on the `CreateQuery` line.

What did I do wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Same trouble than in this [other question](/q/42462497/1178314) from you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to transform this native SQL query to an HQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42462497/how-to-transform-this-native-sql-query-to-an-hql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though I consider this a duplicate of [this other question from you](/q/42462497/1178314), here is a separate, more explicit answer here.

[hql](/questions/tagged/hql) does not support sub-queries in `from` statement. (It supports them in other statements, such as in `where` conditions.) You have to rewrite your query without the sub-query in the `from`.

Your sub-query seems to be there only for limiting rows count. Remove the row limit from the query, and use `.SetMaxResults(yourMaxRowCount)` on the HQL query object instead.

There are no needs for the termination statement `;` in HQL, and I do not know if it is supported. I think it is not, better remove it.

```
var query = s.CreateQuery(
    @"select u from vueCorreliser u
        where u.film = :idfilm
            and u.FILM2 not in (
                select c.idfilm from cote c
                    where c.idclient = :idclient)
        order by u.CORRELATION desc")
    .SetInt32("idfilm", idfilm)
    .SetInt32("idclient", idclient)
    .SetMaxResults(4);
```

That should fix the `QuerySyntaxException`.

By the way, your usage pattern of transaction is not safe. When using locally scoped transactions, always nest them in `using` for ensuring they are properly closed.

```
using (var tx = session.BeginTransaction())
{
    ...
    tx.Commit();
    return result;
}
```

Even in case of failure, the transaction will then always be disposed, which causes it to rollback if it were still ongoing.

Comment: I actually  have forgotten about that other question , but will try to avoid that in further question . Thank you for taking time answering my issue , I very appreciate that